# Carrierwave Backgrounder consuming AWS EC2 resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, carrierwave-backgrounder

I recently added the [`carrierwave_backgrounder` gem](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) to my project - and since then have seen some usage of my EC2 resources (I previously did not use them at all).

How can I instead process versions of my files within the current process (worker) as I did without the gem and just upload them to s3 - significantly reducing costs?

Comment: out of curiosity, what resources do you mean when you say 'ec2 resources'? Is it adding up on your billing or just slowing your instance down?

Comment: @kiddorails billing. As I said, I'm not using it otherwise.